# Google Docs - Table of contents with paging

Tags: google-docs, tableofcontents, page-numbering

I am working on my Google Docs file and wondering if someone knows how it is possible to make a table of contents with page numbering ?

The built-in table of contents won't show numbering.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Install the Google Add-on called Paragraph Styles+. The feature for Table of Contents with page numbers is currently in alpha. If you already have a Table of Contents in your document then remove it. Then add a new Table of Contents: Add-ons > Paragraph Styles+ > Add table of contents. Then add page numbers: Add-ons > Paragraph Styles+ > Add page numbers.

Comment: is there a way to make it do the ...... (dot, dot, dot, etc...) feature to the page number?

Comment: I personnaly download the doc in word, create there the table of content, and copy paste it back to the google doc

Comment: This was such a bad answer. Paragraph Styles+ requires a lot of intrusive permissions. WHY?

Comment: Paragraph Styles+ still has many issues. Even for simple layouts it often does not display the correct page numbers and refreshing page numbers takes quite a long time. It might eventually become a fully-fledged solution, but presently it still feels buggy and incomplete.

Comment: Not happy that it gives straight access to all my documents.

Comment: This is now supported natively, so there's no need for add-ons. See other answers for more up-to-date content.

Answer (score 7):

No need for Plug-ins, workarounds or making excuses for Google any more.

Years in the making but, believe it or not, [Numbered Table of Contents](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/10/page-numbers-now-in-table-of-contents.html?m=1) are now supported natively in "G Suite".

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, page numbers are not currently supported in a table of contents in Google Docs unfortunately. I believe there is a lot of support for Google to add in the functionality though.

Another thread on Stack Exchange has suggested some workarounds for it (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20839/putting-page-numbers-in-a-table-of-contents-in-google-docs), but this may not look very elegant.

Comment: The 'workaround' involves manually typing the page number into the header title. And keeping it up-to-date yourself. 
Basically you can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Table of contents are now [supported natively in Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/116338?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

To add a TOC:

1. Open a document in Google Docs.
2. Click where you want the table of contents.
3. Click **Insert** and then **Table of contents**.
4. Choose **With page numbers** or **With blue links**.
5. The table of contents will appear.

To delete it, right-click and click **Delete table of contents**.

Comment: Still missing the "dot" feature thought.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2016 Google Docs has the option to insert a table of contents with page numbering :)